# Why used @Service and why @Service("") with string parameter in spring?

Tags: spring

why used @Service without string parameter and with string parameter in spring service implementation calsses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Service` without parameter has a default service name, generally it is the same with your class name but the first character is lower case.

For example,

```
@Service
class LoadService {}
```

The default service name is *loadService*

And `@Service(value = "serviceName")` explicitly specify a service name.

For example,

```
@Service(value = "myServiceName")
class LoadService {}
```

The service name is *myServiceName*

From spring docs:

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
>         to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

So, when a project has more than two class whose name is the same and they both have `@Service` annotation, you should use `@Service` with parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, **to be turned into a
> Spring bean in case of an autodetected component**.
>
> Returns:the suggested component name, if any
>
> Default:""

So, you can declare a @Service like this:

```
@Service
public class AppleService{
    ...
}
```

And the bean name will be assigned based on BeanNameGenerator (in this example, it would be **appleService**). Or you can define the name you want to give your bean:

```
@Service("appleSrv")
public class AppleService{
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps :)